# How to have dropdown selection populate DataTables table in template from Django model?

Tags: django, django-models, datatables, django-forms

Hopefully I can get some help with this. I've basically got a page on my site with a table, and the table is populated from the database with my models. My problem, is that I'd like to have a dropdown, where the user can select what data they want to see. I know that I need to use a django form in order to do this, but I've been searching, and have been having a really hard time finding what I need to do. The table is made with DataTables, and a bit of BS4 styling.

Right now, I have the table being populated with just one of my models (Model1) and that's working great, but I'm not sure how to do what I want to do with making a selection from the dropdown, to populate with a different model. I kinda understand how forms work, but I'm not sure how to implement them how I want to. A lot of the stuff I see is just showing how to do a form with one model.

Any sort of example, or guidance would be greatly appreciated :)

Here's my models.py:

```
    class Model1(models.Model):

            date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Date', primary_key=True, default='', max_length=40) 
            data1 = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='NoData', blank=True, null=True, db_column='data1',)
            data2 = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='NoData', blank=True, null=True, db_column='data2',)
            class Meta:
                    managed = True
                    db_table = 'table1'
            def __str__(self):
            return '%s %s %s' % (str(self.date), self.data1, self.data2,)

    class Model2(models.Model):

            date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Date', primary_key=True, default='', max_length=40) 
            data1 = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='NoData', blank=True, null=True, db_column='data1',)
            data2 = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='NoData', blank=True, null=True, db_column='data2',)
            class Meta:
                    managed = True
                    db_table = 'table2'
            def __str__(self):
            return '%s %s %s' % (str(self.date), self.data1, self.data2,)

    class Model3(models.Model):

            date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Date', primary_key=True, default='', max_length=40) 
            data1 = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='NoData', blank=True, null=True, db_column='data1',)
            data2 = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='NoData', blank=True, null=True, db_column='data2',)
            class Meta:
                    managed = True
                    db_table = 'table3'
            def __str__(self):
            return '%s %s %s' % (str(self.date), self.data1, self.data2,)
```

Here's my views.py:

```
from app.models import Model1, Model2, Model3
from django.shortcuts import render

def Appview(request):
    template_name = 'app/app.html'

    Model1 = Model1.objects.all()
    Model2 = Model2.objects.all()
    Model3 = Model3.objects.all()
    return render(request, template_name, {'Model1': Model1})
```

Here's my (simplified) app.html:

```
<div class="table-responsive container">
      <table id = "table" class = "table table-sm table-hover" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Data1</th>
                <th>Data2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            {% for data in Model1 %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ data.date }}</td> 
                <td>{{ data.data1 }}</td>
                <td>{{ data.data2 }}</td>    
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

The real gut of the question is this: How do I make a dropdown form that re-populates the view/template with a different model?

EDIT: The models have many more fields, and the tables are much bigger than shown. I just trimmed things down for simplicity. Looking a bit deeper, I think I might need to use AJAX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't include your form, but it could be something as simple as:

```
class DataForm(forms.Form):
    model = forms.CharField()
```

Then you'd put the form somewhere in your template:

```
<form method="get">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

In your view you would process the `GET` request:

```
def Appview(request):
    models = {
        'model1': Model1,
        'model2': Model2,
        'model3': Model3,
    }    
    template_name = 'app/app.html'
    data = Model1.objects.all()

    if 'model' in request.GET:
        form = DataForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid()
            model = form.cleaned_data['model']
            model = models[model]
            data = model.objects.all()
    else:
        form = DataForm()
    return render(request, template_name, {'data': data, 'form': form})
```

I didn't include validation (you'd want to make sure the `model` exists), but it's just to give you an idea. The logic could also be more complex if you don't want a default model.

Comment: Wow, could it really be that simple? I will give that a shot!

Comment: I got it! I used a ChoiceField, to get my dropdown. I'd rather have it JUST update the table itself, instead of reloading the entire page, but for now this works swimmingly. I'll reach for the AJAX can of worms some other day LOL.

Comment: Great! Yes, of course `ChoiceField` is much better, and AJAX will make it smoother.